# Two ways of Writing Expectation of $X$

Tags: probability

Consider a discrete random variable $X$.

I would like to show that: another way of writing $E(X)=\sum\limits_{s\in S}  X(s)P(\{s\})$ is:

> $E(X)=\sum\limits_{x\in X} xP(X=x).$

$\textbf{My Question:}$ Is my proof below correct?

Proof:

\begin{align}
E(X)&=\sum\limits_{x\in X} xP(X=x)=\sum\limits_{x\in X}\sum\limits_{s:X(s)=x}xP(\{s\})\\
&=\sum\limits_{x\in X}x\underbrace{\sum\limits_{s:X(s)=x}P(\{s\})}_{\text{by definition, } P(X=x)}\\
&=\sum\limits_{x\in X}xP(X=x).
\end{align}

Reference:
Blitzstein, J. K., & Hwang, J. (2014). $\textit{Introduction to probability.}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do you mean? The expression you commented with is just putting equal weights for all the pebbles in the sample space. How is this confusing?

Comment: The notation is correct if $S$ is the universe and is countable. The proof however is just a proof that $\sum x P(x) = \sum x P(x)$. you may want to go from $\sum_s X(s) P(\{s\})$ to $\sum_x x P(x)$. One way of doing so is to write as you notice $P(x) = \sum_{s:X(s)=x} P(\{s \})$

Comment: @P.Quinton I am sorry, I don't still understand which part is exactly, perhaps, illicit to write. Can you please elaborate in a response? I would appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your proof the steps are correct but then you fall back to the same side of the equality you want to prove. You can use the same steps as you did :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X] &= \sum_{s\in\mathcal S} X(s) \mathbb P[\{s\}]\\
&= \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum_{s\in\mathcal S:X(s)=x} X(s) \mathbb P[\{s\}]\\
&= \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} \sum_{s\in\mathcal S:X(s)=x} x \mathbb P[\{s\}]\\
&= \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} x \sum_{s\in\mathcal S:X(s)=x}  \mathbb P[\{s\}]\\
&= \sum_{x\in \mathcal X} x  \mathbb P[X=x]
\end{align*}